# Computing Displacement Potential functions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

### I am new to Mathematica.
I am trying to compute the displacement Potential functions. My code is as follows.

```
u = {Ur*Sin[\[Theta]], U\[Theta]*Cos[\[Theta]]}
\[Xi] = 1 - 2*\[Nu];
\[Lambda] = (2*G*\[Nu])/(1 - 2*\[Nu]);
eps = (Grad[u, {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] + 
    Transpose[Grad[u, {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"]])/2 // Simplify // 
  MatrixForm
sig = \[Lambda]*Tr[eps]*IdentityMatrix[2] + 2*G*eps // Simplify 
Div[sig, {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] // Simplify
DSolve[{(G ((-1+2 \[Nu]) (Ux^(0,2))[x,y]-(Uy^(1,1))[x,y]+2 \
(-1+\[Nu]) (Ux^(2,0))[x,y]))/(-1+2 \[Nu])==0,
(G (2 (-1+\[Nu]) (Uy^(0,2))[x,y]-(Ux^(1,1))[x,y]+(-1+2 \[Nu]) \
(Uy^(2,0))[x,y]))/(-1+2 \[Nu])==0},{Ux,Uy},{x,y}]//Simplify
```

---

u is my displacement vector, and I want to find the value of Ux and Uy.
Can you please help me in fixing this code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. `MatrixForm` is for display purposes only, so use `eps // MatrixForm` at the end if you want to display this as a matrix. Please load definitions for all your variables. To make sure this happens, start a notebook with a fresh kernel and copy code from your post/paste and run. Whatever shows up in blue color remains undefined yet. Thanks.

Comment: Change the eps line to

      (eps = (Grad[u, {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] + 
       Transpose[Grad[u, {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"]])/2 // 
        Simplify) // MatrixForm

Your eps is a print format.

Comment: 1. In the first half of your code you define cylindrical components of the displacement vector and make operations with them. In its second part you suddenly try to solve an equation formulated for Cartesian displacements. These two parts are not related to one another.

Comment: 2. Equation of mechanical equilibrium (the one you write under the `DSolve` operator) cannot be solved in a general form. It is a generally known fact. For this reason, Mathematica also cannot solve it in the form you requested. One needs to put specific boundary conditions together with  `NDSolve` .

Comment: 3. Last-not least: `Ux^(0, 2))[x, y]` is a syntactic error. You should write it as follows: `D[U[x,y],{y,2}]`. There are several other correct alternative ways.

Comment: Thank you @Syed and @Alexei!